# E/StorageException: Unable to obtain an upload URL

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I don't know why I'm getting this exception E/StorageException: Unable to obtain an upload URL whenever it gets to uploading file/image onto Firebase Storage. It's also returning W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request error. Although I don't experience any internet connectivity problems. I've also tried running this with another device but it results in the same thing.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail, inputPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<Void> task) {

                                    final String uID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("image").child(uID); // for image uploads

                                        storageReference.putFile(image_uri)
                                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                        //image uri is taken care of in the onActivityResult method.
                                                        member.setImage_url(taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString());
                                                        member.setEmail(email.getText().toString().trim());
                                                        member.setFname(fname.getText().toString().trim());
                                                        member.setLname(lname.getText().toString().trim());

                                                        df = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member").child(uID); //points to the address
                                                        df.setValue(member).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, Login.class));
                                                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered successfully, please verify your email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                        RprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                    }
                                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                RprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        RprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            RprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still only have the slightest idea of what is happening but I've seen some other answers from a similar post and they suggested using VPN I'm currently in the Philippines so if anyone is having a similar problem try using VPN.